# adding a favicon to site2 - site1/site2/favicon.ico

Tags: css, favicon

I have a setup on wordpress with site1 and site2 under site1.
I'm having problem on favicon on site2 because site2 favicon uses the favicon for site1.

i have a code on my header.php inside site2

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

and i also put my favicon.ico file on the root and inside the theme im using but no success.

Comment: marking as possible off-topic as  what browsers are doing with the info you send them is unrelated to wordpress.

Comment: im using wordpress for my cms. with 2 site conflicting my favicon.

Answer (score 0):

For me its showing different on Safari and different on chrome. When I checked page source, I noticed favicon is being called thrice. Please delete other two instances and then check clearing browser cache for all browsers. I believe it should work then.

Comment: It must be cache. Please rename your favicon file to something else. Say hotelfs.ico and use this tag instead of earlier.

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/hotelfs.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 


It should work.

Comment: still the same on my chrome but its good on my other browser. I have clear my cache still the same.

Comment: @MichaelPon - Thats a mystery!! I just exported ico image to png and used that. Its working. I tested on chrome, FF, Safari. Am on Mac so can't test on IE. So please use png for favicon and that should do. Thanks.

 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/hotelfs.png" />

Comment: Yes, after using png do clear browser cache.